# How to index and serve poems using apache solr

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am using solr 4.10. I have to index poetry data in solr. Now what should be the document structure. Basically, I want to  give a search facility for a term in poem. Only that specific distich should be given back. Now should I index complete poem in single document or one document per distich. I know some poems have two lines for single concept and some 4 etc. Now What should be its storing format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the distiches individually and link them through a poem identifier and a sequence id. That way you can also retrieve the distich before or after - or the whole poem.

If there's certain use cases that need to treat the poems as a whole instead, create a separate collection and index to both collections. That way you can adjust and tweak the search results as you need, depending on the use case.

Comment: I was also thinking this solution